# Render to texture performance extremely bad on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

In my Cocos2d-X based game, I render to an offscreen framebuffer for post processing. On the iPhone 4S this works without a problem and the effect along with the rest of the game is rendered effortlessly at 60 FPS. On Android however, the FPS drop from 60FPS to 20-30 FPS, whenever I use the effect. I even tried to decrease the size of the framebuffer from 0.5 * screensize to 0.25 * screensize but the FPS drop is still noticeable (resulting in ~37 FPS).

I tested it on a Nexus 7 (2013) and a Motorola Moto G. I also tried the glClear tweak for Qualcomm GPUs but without luck.

Are FBOs on Android really so expensive that I should drop the effect completely or is there more to it?

Comment: On which frame processing phase FBO is used? If FBO used in `visit` or `draw` functions, in will affect persformance. `update` or other scheduler events is right place for FBO.

Comment: Wow that really did it! Thank you for saving me hours. I should've thought of that by myself. If you post it as an answer you'll get the correct answer tick.